# Visual Studio 17.5 ViewComponents not being invoked anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Yesterday I updated Visual Studio 2022 Community edition from 17.4 to 17.5 (MS Windows)

All of a sudden the ViewComponents in my #NET 7 web application are not invoked and not rendered anymore. I didn't make any changes to my code.

Before going into details: does anybody else face this problem as well? Seems to be a bug in VS 2022, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in 17.5, it has been raised on [MS Developer Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/RazorPages-ViewComponents-not-rendering/10289877?sort=newest&q=ViewComponents) yesterday (23/02/2023)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I had looked in there the day before yesterday. Must have overlapped. So, it is a bug in VS. Thanks again!